# Clicking on the link inside the Geckofx webbrowser will trigger the method in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, geckofx

There is an HTML file with named "test.html" and two links in it. This HTML file is shown in `geckoWebBrowser1` as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="tr">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" id="open_file" class="open-file button" onclick="openFile()">Open A PDF file...</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="go_to_articles" class="go-to-articles button" onclick="goToArticles()">Go to articles...</a></p>
</body>
<script>
    function openFile()
    {
        // What should I write here?
    }

    function goToArticles()
    {
        // What should I write here?
    }
</script>
</html>
```

And here is the winforms content:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gecko;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Frm1 : Form
    {

        public Frm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox64");
        }
        private void Frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("start\\test.html");
        }

        public void OpenPDFFile()
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = @"PDF |*.pdf", Title = @"Select a PDF file..." };
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Here, action will be taken regarding the selected file.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the `Open A PDF file ...` link in the HTML file, the `OpenPDFFile` method must be triggered in Winforms and selected the PDF file from the dialog box, but I have not been able to do so. Yet I would like to see the "FrmArticles" form located in Winforms by clicking the `Go to articles ...` link in the HTML file, but I have not been able to achieve it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is derived from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48044046/1827846) to the [Error in 'AddMessageEventListener' on GeckoFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859864/error-in-addmessageeventlistener-on-geckofx) question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="tr">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" id="open_file" class="open-file button" onclick="fireEvent('openFiles', 'SomeData');">Open A PDF file...</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="go_to_articles" class="go-to-articles button" onclick="goToArticles()">Go to articles...</a></p>
</body>
<script>
function fireEvent(name, data)
{
    var event = new MessageEvent(name,{'view': window, 'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': true, 'data': data});
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
</script>
</html>
```

`Form.cs` content,

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gecko;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Frm1 : Form
    {

        public Frm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox64");
        }
        private void Frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("start\\test.html");
            AddMessageEventListener("openFiles", showMessage);
        }


        public void AddMessageEventListener(string eventName, Action<string> action)
        {
            geckoWebBrowser1.AddMessageEventListener(eventName, action);
        }

        private void showMessage(string s)
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = @"PDF |*.pdf", Title = @"Select a PDF file..." };
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ofd.FileName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In the example, you can use the string "SomeData" as a parameter if you want.